# Fancybox and jwplayer group images and video issue in ipad

Tags: fancybox

I have fancybox / jwmediaplayer gallery with mixed video and images i am able to play the video in desktop browsers but in ipad when i click next from the image gallery i can see only loading. check the below code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $(".jwVideo").click(function() {
        var myVideo = this.href; // Dont forget about 'this'
        $.fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            content: '<div id="video_container" style="width:640px;height:385px;">Loading the player ... </div>',
            autoSize: true,
            helpers : { 
            title : { type : 'inside' }
          },
            afterShow: function(){
                jwplayer("video_container").setup({ 

                    file: myVideo,
                    autostart: 'true',
                    width: 640,
                    height: 385,`enter code here`
                    modes: [
        { type: 'html5' },
        { type: 'flash', src: 'assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf' }
    ]

                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});  
 });
```